# React-Redux Data Consistency (When to make API calls?)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've seen examples of both "eventually consistent" and "strongly consistent" data flows in various React-Redux examples.

"Eventually consistent" flows dispatch and action to mutate the local store, optimistically update the UI, make an API call, and ignore the results if the response is OK.

"Strongly consistent" flows set an isUpdating flag in the store, make an API call, mutate state on API response, then update the UI.

Are either one of these preferred over the other? What is best practice?

Comment: Neither is best practice.. it depends on what your app needs are. If it was a banking app, eventually consistent would be frightening if things rolled back. Your transaction went through! Oops, no it didn't..!

Comment: From the UI perspective, sure... don't surprise the user. 

But I'm more curious if mutating the local store should be deferred until the API calls return.

Many Redux tutorials tend to mutate the local store first, obviously to demonstrate Redux. But in practice, I wonder if it's best to make API calls first (?)